# changing field in a set object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this document in mongo:

```
{
    id: objectId,
    list: [ 
    {
        id: internalObjectId1,
        enabled: true
    },
    {
        id: internalObjectId2,
        enabled: false
    }]
}
```

I need to change the enabled field. How can I do it?

Comment: here some confusion don't understand you want to change `enabled` key to other key name or `enabled` value `true` to convert `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[positional $ operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)**. Suppose you have the following document in the collection whose `list` element value is an array of embedded documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("551be1a04db8a16ac729432e"),
    "list" : [ 
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("54f43159c922ac0b4387ef9c"),
            "enabled" : true
        }, 
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("54f43159c922ac0b4387ef9d"),
            "enabled" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

The following will update the value of the `enabled` field in the embedded document with the `id` of `54f43159c922ac0b4387ef9d` to `true`:

```
db.collection.update(
   { 
        "_id": ObjectId("551be1a04db8a16ac729432e"), 
       "list.id": ObjectId("54f43159c922ac0b4387ef9d") 
   },
   { 
       "$set": {"list.$.enabled": true} 
   }
)
```